# Need comments on low noise band-pass filter design

Tags: analog, filter

I am a beginner in filter design. This is the bandpass filter and its central frequency is 2kHz. Would you please give me some comments on this design?[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question lacks a question.

Comment: What aspects of the design do you want comments on?  Be very specific.

Comment: The title of your question hints that you might have an issue with noise. What signal levels are you working with, and how much noise is "too much"? Be specific.

Comment: 10 nVRMS seems like an awfully small input signal. Do you have a lot of gain in this filter?

Answer (score 3):

1st stage is a 1.9995 kHz bandpass filter using a standard multiple-feedback topology. It has a Q of about 20 and a gain of about 40 dB.

2nd stage is a 2.009 kHz BP filter with a Q of about 25 and a gain of about 40 dB.

Total gain of first stage is 40 dB which makes a 10nV 2 kHz signal into 1 microvolt.

Bandwidth of 1st stage is \$\dfrac{f_C}{Q}\$ = 100Hz and for the purposes of noise calculation you can assume the bandwidth is 1.6x greater at 160 Hz.

\$E_{NOISE}\$ from ADA4004 is 1.8nV /\$\sqrt{Hz}\$. This means noise in a 160 Hz bandwidth is 22.8 nV

This is bigger than your signal (10nV) therefore this isn't going to be a great design.

Even if you took into account the Q of the 2nd stage, the bandwidth would only be halved i.e. a half power point would become a quarter-power point. Noise voltage would be about 16 nV and still a significantly bigger value than your signal. This is made worse by the 2nd stage being 9.5 Hz different to the 1st stage.

Comment: 36nV just from the 487 ohm resistor...

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - that's the wideband noise I guess?

Comment: Nope it's the in-band noise!!!!

Comment: 160Hz BW, assuming 300K temperature!

Comment: @SpehroPefhany yeah I just checked!!! Dear OP - here is a resistor noise calculator: http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-noise.htm

Comment: Is that noise input or output referenced??  Do you need to multiply the noise by the gain?

Comment: @ScottSeidman - it's noise input referenced